# Issue with opining video URL on electron desktop application

Tags: electron

I build an electron desktop application, and when I click on any anchor link tag ; all HTML content was removed and I ended up with video-tag and I was unable to go back to the main page!

```
<a href="https://hostname/directory/video.mp4">video name</a>
```

Even Reload and force-Reload in the development mode doesn't Work!

Comment: What is the desired behavior ?

Answer (score 0):

When you click on a link, Electron opens that URL.

If you want to display a video on the page just use a video tag:

```html
<video 
  src="https://hostname/directory/video.mp4"
  controls 
  height="200"
  width="300"
></video>
```

If you want to open this link in the default browser, you have to open it externally:

```html
<button onclick="openExternal('https://hostname/directory/video.mp4')">
  video name
</button>
```

```js
const { shell } = require('electron')

function openExternal (link) {
  shell.openExternal(link)
}
```